# Round Up Integer Division

Tags: .net, vb.net, math, division

If I have given a certain lines per page and have to find how many pages have been used. if I divide it, still I don't get 2 pages :

```
   Dim lines As Integer = 68
    Dim lines_per_page As Integer = 65
    Dim pages_used As Integer
    Pages_used =  lines_per_page / lines
```

Can you help please.

Comment: What output do you get for the above code?  *if I divide it, still I don't get 2 pages* isn't very specific. If you don't want Pages_used = 1 as the output, then you should use decimal or double for the dim type.

Comment: @Somantra I get 1 when executing it. if i use decimal or double i get 0.955882352941176

Comment: Exactly what output are you trying to achieve? it is not clear in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing your division backwards.  You must divide total lines by lines-per-page. See how the terms cancel in this way:

x pages = (y lines/1 page) / (z lines)  << yeilds 1/pages (wrong!)

x pages = (z lines) / (y lines/1 page) = (z lines) * (1 page / y lines) << correct!

Also note that you need to perform double division, not integer division, then round the resulting value up since a partial page must be rounded to a full page.

```
Dim lines As Integer = 68 
Dim lines_per_page As Double = 65 
Dim pages_used As Integer 
pages_used = CType(Math.Ceiling(lines / lines_per_page), Integer)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note: This solution utilizes your provided parameters with no change in type. Roken's solution is correct in logic, but will not compile as pages_used is cast as an integer.**

Use the following:

```
Dim lines As Integer = 68
Dim lines_per_page As Integer = 65
Dim pages_used As Integer

pages_used = (lines + lines_per_page - 1) \ lines_per_page
```

Result: `pages_used = 2`

Comment: (+1) This is sound and visually cleaner than my example, but less self-documenting (calculation's behavior is not immediately obvious). Personally, I would use this, however I think it's important to illustrate the issues and solutions to a fundamental question like this.

Comment: Yea, I didn't want to disagree with your solution at all, because it solves the fundamental problem. The only reason I added the note was due to the lack of usage of pages_used outside of the provided code snippet. I also see you got your CType call correctly set up :) (+1).

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have Pages_Used as an integer.  VB is going to round the result.  Try using a double instead.

Comment: I get 1 when executing it. if i use decimal or double i get 0.955882352941176

Comment: but if I divide the other way round(pages_used = lines / lines_per_page) I get 1.04615384615385

Comment: Sam1, you want the 1.046.  You are looking at 68 total lines, but only 65 can fit on a sheet.  This gives you 1 + some fraction.  If you had 680 lines at 65 pages a sheet, you should expect to see 10.46 as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

what is wrong here is you are reversing the division. You should divide the lines bu line per page thus

**Pages_used =   lines / lines_per_page**

not the other way round.